# Zoom to coordinate from form-input in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I want to in Leaflet write a coordinatepair (lat/long) in a form and then click a button to zoom to the coordinatepair.

I'm really new on this.

Answer (score 7):

To zoom to a point in Leaflet, you can use *PanTo*:
([Leaflet Doc #PanTo](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panto))

```
map.panTo(new L.LatLng(47, 15));
```

Create a text input field for Latitude and Longitude in HTML, and a button as well.

```
Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat"/>
Longitude: <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng"/>
<input type="button" onclick="zoomTo()" value="zoomTo"/>
```

Read the values with Javascript and put it in PanTo method:

```
function zoomTo() {
    var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
    var lng = document.getElementById("lng").value;
    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
}
```

Here's a code chunk, runable and tested:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        #mapid { height: 500px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat"/>
    <br/>
    Longitude: <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="zoomTo()" value="zoomTo"/>
    <div id="mapid"></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    function zoomTo() {
        var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
        var lng = document.getElementById("lng").value;
        map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as a quick example:

HTML

```
<input id="myForm" type="text" value="Type here">
<button onclick="zoom2latLng();">Zoom to Coords</button>
```

javascript

```
// get input
var inputLatLng = document.getElementById('myForm').value;
// declare leaflet latlng
var latlng = L.latLng(inputLatLng);  // ie. 50.5, 30.5
// declare leaflet map
var map = L.map('map' .... ;

function zoom2latLng() {
    map.flyTo(latlng);  // you can specify pan/zoom options as well
};
```

This is just an example; not runnable code.
Pulled from the [leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html)