# Zoom to centroid of polygon from form-input in Leaflet

Tags: postgis, leaflet, php

I want to  write the name of the polygon in a form and then click a button to zoom or to flyto to the centroid of the polygon. I've writen a request in PHP that give the centroid of the polygon.

```
function localiser5() {
  var val6 = document.getElementById('val6').value;
  console.log(val6);
  var x;
  var y;
  var z;
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/survoler.php',

      data: {
        val6 : val6
      },
      success:function(data){

     map.flyTo(new L.LatLng(x, y),12);  
      },
      error:function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
    })

}
```

PHP:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=d3topo user=postgres password=khadija") or die('could not connect :'.pg_last_error());

if(!empty($_POST['val6'])){
  $nom_table='points_rattachement';
  $champ_geometrique = 'geom';
  $val6 = $_POST['val6'];

  $sql = "SELECT st_x(st_centroid(geom)) as x, st_y(st_centroid(geom)) as y
          FROM plan_situation where nom_plan='".$val6."'";




  $rs = pg_query($db, $sql);
  if (!$rs) {
    echo "Erreur SQL survenue!.\n";
    exit;
  }
  $testRow = pg_fetch_row($rs);
  echo $testRow[0];

}
```

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" placeholder="Nom plan" name="val6" id="val6" />  
<button type="submit" onClick="localiser5()" >FlyTo Polygon </button>
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: where exactly ?

Comment: where, indeed...we do need a question ,) where is your problem? be specific.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to select the polygon and zoom to it. The way this is worded you could have an array of objects name, X, Y, and just use the setView with a constant zoom set. Problem with this is if each polygon is a different size you may not see all of the polygon. You would also have to capture different zoom scales to show each polygon.

For a class I used a simple JQuery Autocomplete input and wrote up how to zoom and highlight a "selected" polygon. From this page I have my code and a working example.

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Search/index.html

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213465/zoom-to-coordinate-from-form-input-in-leaflet?rq=1